# How to add a span class in the post title?

Tags: title

I need to add a span class in the post title, something like this:

[image: See this picture (a picture is worth a thousand words!).]

How to do that? Is this possible?

Comment: is it always the same content within the span tag?

Comment: It's more convinient to add custom field right into the theme customization panel with hook: http://learnwebtutorials.com/wordpress-adding-fields-to-the-theme-customization-panel

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the simplest approach be to use a filter on the_title()?

```
function add_span($title, $id) {

    return $title .' <span class="title_span">' .get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single) ."</span>";

}

add_filter('the_title', 'add_span', 10, 2);
```

This approach of course assumes you're storing your span data as a meta value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the HTML on the image is not valid - close your `<span>` with `</span>`.

And yes, it's possible. I would do it with a custom field where you would enter what you want in your `<span></span>` and then just display it in the theme file wherever you want it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this thing.

1. you can use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method of jquery.
2. Other way is to edit the header.php of your theme file and make the changes as required.
3. follow [this](http://digwp.com/2010/04/custom-page-titles/) tutorial so as to give desired title to each individual post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom meta key instead of your title area.

**Simple usage :** (Replace `<?php the_title(); ?>` in your theme with this lines)

```
<?php $html_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, "HTML_title", true); if ($html_title) { ?>               
   <h1><?php echo $html_title; ?></h1>     
   <?php } else { ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Type your html codes in your HTML_title meta box than get your magic (:

Happy wordpress.